# Appcelerator Tableview not displaying rows when returning to View

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I have a nasty bug when using `Tableviews` on `Appcelerator`.

When I enter the app the user is promoted to enter a username and a password then i fetch data from a Server and display it in the `Tableview`.

There is a filter method to get specific items from the Server. They are send via a `Json` and i convert them to `TableViewRows`.

this works like a charm even multiple times. But when i click on a Row it opens a new View (where the user can interact with the data provided for this row)

The problem starts when I'm returning to that previous view where the `TableView` is.

It doesn't work anymore.

It does not matter how i populate the `TableView` data 
`TableView.data=someData` doesn't work, `TableView.setData(someData)` doesn't work and setting a Timeout to set the Data also does not work.

After adding the Data by the described methods above, the `Tableview` does not Show the Data. But if i Debug it i can see that the new Rows are added to the `Tableview` but are not Displayed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What SDK version are you on? We've had a bug where sometimes the TableView/ListView was displayed empty, but it should be fixed in 5.x

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen dude, I also having the same problem with this...using 5.0.2GA currently...

Comment: Could either of you create a JIRA ticket at jira.appcelerator.org with reproducible code/steps/environment?